# Remote server login error

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Hi I want to login into my remote server using power shell . I wrote code for this but I am getting error .

**CODE**

```
  $cred = get-credential - Prompts for username and password
  Enter-PSSession -ComputerName  servername -Credential $cred
```

**ERROR**

> Get-Credential : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument 'Prompts'.At  C:\documents\Untitled8.ps1:1 char:9
>   + $cred = get-credential - Prompts for username and password
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Credential], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCredentialCommand
>
> Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server XXXXX failed with the
>   following error message : Access is denied.  For more information, see
>   the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.At
>   C:\documents\Untitled8.ps1:5 char:1
>   + Enter-PSSession -ComputerName  servername -Credential $cred
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (servername:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed

Any clue regarding this will help....
**`Get-Credential : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Prompts'`**

Anybody have any clue how to login into remote server in power shell using servername..any clue any link regarding this will be helpful

Comment: "- Prompts for username and password" seems to be text for the user.  Precede it with a hash (#) symbol to turn it into a comment: #- Prompts for username and password

Comment: thanks for reply :) ..it solved the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there it can´t find a positional parameter, where "Prompts" is accepted. If you look at the help file for Get-credential you will see that the -Credential paramenter is positional, meaning you dont need to type it.

Try with this

```
  $cred = get-credential -Message "Prompts for username and password"
  Enter-PSSession -ComputerName  servername -Credential $cred
```

Some reading about positional parameters
https://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/powershell/positional-parameters/